# durandal applybindings how to

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

Very new to Durandal but have been using knockout for some time. I created a js module and an html page that contains knockout bindings, however the knockout is being ignored (as though applybindings did not run). I am not getting any errors in the console.

Does durandal automatically run applybindings, or do I need to do that somehow in Activate()?

This is my code:

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout','plugins/dynamiccss'], function (http, app, ko,cssLoader) {

    var ctor = function () {
        this.compositionComplete = function () {
            cssLoader.loadCss("Content/css/tables.css");
        };
        this.deactivate = function () {
            cssLoader.removeModuleCss();
        }
        this.awards = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.activate = function () {
            var that = this;
            return $.ajax({
                url: 'Budget/GetAwards',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                context: this,
                data: ko.toJSON({Id:'1'}),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf8',
                async: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    that.awards(response.Model);
                }
            });

        }

    };


    return ctor;
});
```

this is the html:

```
<section>
    <h2 data-bind="html:displayName"></h2>

    <table class="input-cells">
        <thead><tr><th>Award Number</th><th>Pipeline Sector</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:awards">
            <tr>
                <td><b data-bind="text:AwardNumber"></b></td>
                <td><select data-bind="options:['test1','test2','test3'],value:PipelineSectorId"></select></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

This is all behaving as though applybindings never happened. Any suggestions how to debug?

Thanks!

Comment: is the name of the js file exactly the same as the html file?

Comment: First I would check that your `success` is being called or not? And I don't see in your viewmodel a property called `displayName` but you have it in your html: `<h2 data-bind="html:displayName"></h2>`

Comment: the files are called index.html and index.js in the same folder, this is being called by a sub-router just like the knockout examples pages

Comment: Success is executing correctly. The awards variable contains what it should.

Comment: i removed displayname and something different is happening now I am debugging, thanks that helped

Comment: Got it working! thanks everyone for the suggestions. It was the displayname binding. It looks like if a binding throws an error Durandal eats the error and fails silently.

Comment: Normally the console will *always* show binding failures.  Make sure you are viewing "ALL" messages in your console of choice.

Comment: Now I see, it displays them as messages not errors.